# Room - The connection pool for database '/data/.../db' has been unable to grant a connection to thread with flags 0x2 for X seconds

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room, android-livedata

### Error Message

```
The connection pool for database '/data/data/com.app.test/databases/test-db' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 9734 (pool-3-thread-2) with flags 0x2 for 30.001001 seconds.
    Connections: 1 active, 0 idle, 1 available.

    Requests in progress:
      executeForCursorWindow started 29982ms ago - running, sql="<<Complex SQL Query with an average of 3 LEFT JOINS>>"
```

All over the app, we've used ROOM and LiveData. It was on this fragment that there are multiple observers that are happening (about 9 Observers). And for each LiveData observed there are:

- `Transformations.switchMap()`
- `Transformations.map()`
- Each model has the `@Embedded` annotation, and some have multiple `@Relation` annotations.

### Observations

- The error message keeps on flooding the LogCat until I force stop
  the app.
- All other queries won't work.

### Test Environments

- ASUS Nexus  7 (Android 5.1.1) - 100% reproducable
- Lenovo Tab 7 (Android 7.0) - experience it 1x only

---

I did a bit of research but there was none who uses ROOM and experienced this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my observation, I left the device with this issue for almost an hour and found out next that the query proceeded and the SQLite warnings did not log, and the SQL queries are already executed.

I looked into the complex SQL query and found out that the multiple `LEFT JOIN`s (6 of them) caused duplicate records which were handled by the `GROUP BY`.

To prove this observation, I commented out the complex SQL query, and the error cannot be replicated anymore on the ASUS Nexus 7 (Android 5.1.1) device.

In conclusion, for anyone who might encounter the same issue, try to check the execution time of your query and try to optimize it.